# FFMPEG -re Insurance

Tags: ffmpeg

FFMPEG -re according to the ffmpeg docs:

> Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab
> device, or live input stream (e.g. when reading from a file). Should
> not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams (where it
> can cause packet loss).

My ffmpeg stream command is:

```
ffmpeg -re -i https://www.example.com/video.mp4 -filter_complex tpad=start_duration=10:stop_duration=15:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add -af adelay=10000|10000 -maxrate 2M -crf 24 -bufsize 6000k -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -strict -2 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -attempt_recovery 1 -max_recovery_attempts 5 -drop_pkts_on_overflow 1 -f flv rtmp://live.example.com/123453
```

Except this does not always work, and sometimes I have livestreams ending early because ffmpeg is playing faster than the frame rate. Is there another command that can be used to ensure ffmpeg streams the video in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-re` and add filter-based throttling.

`ffmpeg -i https://www.example.com/video.mp4 -filter_complex tpad=start_duration=10:stop_duration=15:start_mode=add:color=black:stop_mode=add,fifo,realtime -af adelay=10000|10000,afifo,arealtime -maxrate 2M -crf 24 -bufsize 6000k -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -strict -2 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -attempt_recovery 1 -max_recovery_attempts 5 -drop_pkts_on_overflow 1 -f flv rtmp://live.example.com/123453`

Comment: Whats the different between -re  and fifo,realtime?

Comment: Also is appears using fifo,realtime creates a substanial amount of lag because of `time discontinuity detected: -2025150 us, resetting`